# Scan each Lines of the file and look for match (|##|) , if found add double quotes in front of next line

Tags: shell, unix

Need your help and Suggestion on the below requirements.

> Read each line and look for '|##|' ( this is my end line char) if found, insert /add Double quotes (") in front or beginning of the next line

Input file #1:

```
101|*|101-C-01071|*|FIRSTLINE|##|
102|*|DOUBT and Stage go to 
and admin|*|SIMCA-ON|##|
103|*|101-C-01071|*|VEEVA|##|
```

Output expected:

```
101|*|101-C-01071|*|FIRSTLINE|##|
"102|*|DOUBT and Stage go to 
and admin|*|SIMCA-ON|##|
"103|*|101-C-01071|*|VEEVA|##|
```

Input file #2:

```
101|*|101-C-01071|*|Integrity Testing of Bleed Back Filter (Emflon II ) Installed on ETC Autoclave|*|PUBLIC|*||*|Y|*|Y|*||*|CFC6E8227CDB0A7AE040800AA5644B19|*|mdarling|*|2007.06.22 09:59:03|##|
102|*|102-CC-10|*|Sterilization and Leak Rate Testing of Stokes Style Freeze Drier|*|PUBLIC|*||*|Y|*|Y|*||*|CFC6E8227CDC0A7AE040800AA5644B19|*|mdarling|*|2007.06.22 10:00:05|##|
103|*|103-CC-13|*|CIP/SIP Leak Testing Hull 380sq. ft. Freeze Drier|*|PUBLIC|*||*|Y|*|Y|*||*|CFC6E8227CDD0A7AE040800AA5644B19|*|mdarling|*|2007.06.22 10:00:16|##|
104|*|104-CC-15|*|Emergency Situations & Alarms Involving the Automated Hull Freeze Drier Control|*|PUBLIC|*||*|Y|*|Y|*||*|CFC6E8227CDE0A7AE040800AA5644B19|*|mdarling|*|2007.06.22 10:00:32|##|
```

Results:

```
101|*|101-C-01071|*|Integrity Testing of Bleed Back Filter (Emflon II ) Installed on ETC Autoclave|*|PUBLIC|*||*|Y|*|Y|*||*|CFC6E8227CDB0A7AE040800AA5644B19|*|mdarling|*|2007.06.22 09:59:03|##|
"102|*|102-CC-10|*|Sterilization and Leak Rate Testing of Stokes Style Freeze Drier|*|PUBLIC|*||*|Y|*|Y|*||*|CFC6E8227CDC0A7AE040800AA5644B19|*|mdarling|*|2007.06.22 10:00:05|##|
103|*|103-CC-13|*|CIP/SIP Leak Testing Hull 380sq. ft. Freeze Drier|*|PUBLIC|*||*|Y|*|Y|*||*|CFC6E8227CDD0A7AE040800AA5644B19|*|mdarling|*|2007.06.22 10:00:16|##|
"104|*|104-CC-15|*|Emergency Situations & Alarms Involving the Automated Hull Freeze Drier Control|*|PUBLIC|*||*|Y|*|Y|*||*|CFC6E8227CDE0A7AE040800AA5644B19|*|mdarling|*|2007.06.22 10:00:32|##|
```

Answer (score 1):

Sed works:

```
sed -n ':a;/|##|/{p;n;s/^/"/;ba;};p;'
```

Live example available at [tutorialpoints](http://tpcg.io/EgMKTD).

Comment: Hi , thanks for the quick response.login as: x2inform
[x2inform@nahas05190 ~]$ cd /informat/Projects/LOS/_INITIAL
[x2inform@nahas05190 _INITIAL]$ sed -n ':a;/|##|$/{p;n;s/^/"/;ba;};p;' <Stack.txt
101|*|101-C-01071|*|FIRSTLINE|##|
102|*|DOUBT and Stage go to
and admin|*|SIMCA-ON|##|
103|*|101-C-01071|*|VEEVA|##|[x2inform@nahas05190 _INITIAL]$

Comment: tried with above sed commands but it not worked form , am i doing any mistake ..attached screenshot below

Comment: I have no idea what you attached (in a comment), check line endings, run it through dos2unix.

Comment: sorry ,i am not able to attach screenshot

Comment: the above command wont work in unix bash ?- im using putty to test

Comment: On tutorialspoint, where the code runs fine, is GNU Bash v4.4 and sed v4.4. Did you check line endings of the input `Stack.txt` file? `sed` may not work with windows's `CRLF` line endings.

Comment: I have written the code so that it catches `|##|` string __on the ending__ of the line. You can remove the `$` from the sed argument to catch `|##|` anywhere in the line.

Comment: Kamil , its worked!! fine after removing $ . thanks for the support

Answer (score 0):

How about awk solution:

```
> cat in_file
101|*|101-C-01071|*|FIRSTLINE|##|
102|*|DOUBT and Stage go to
and admin|*|SIMCA-ON|##|
103|*|101-C-01071|*|VEEVA|##|
> awk -F" " ' { if($0~/\|##\|/) { print; getline; print "\x22"$0 } else { print } } ' in_file
101|*|101-C-01071|*|FIRSTLINE|##|
"102|*|DOUBT and Stage go to
and admin|*|SIMCA-ON|##|
"103|*|101-C-01071|*|VEEVA|##|
>
```

**EDIT1:**

```
> cat double_quote.txt
101||101-C-01071||Integrity Testing of Bleed Back Filter (Emflon II ) Installed on ETC
Autoclave||PUBLIC||||Y||Y||||CFC6E8227CDB0A7AE040800AA5644B19||mdarling||2007.06.22
09:59:03|##| 102||102-CC-10||Sterilization and Leak Rate Testing of Stokes Style Freeze
Drier||PUBLIC||||Y||Y||||CFC6E8227CDC0A7AE040800AA5644B19||mdarling||2007.06.22
10:00:05|##| 103||103-CC-13||CIP/SIP Leak Testing Hull 380sq. ft. Freeze
Drier||PUBLIC||||Y||Y||||CFC6E8227CDD0A7AE040800AA5644B19||mdarling||2007.06.22
10:00:16|##| 104||104-CC-15||Emergency Situations & Alarms Involving the Automated Hull Freeze
Drier Control||PUBLIC||||Y||Y||||CFC6E8227CDE0A7AE040800AA5644B19||mdarling||2007.06.22
10:00:32|##| strong text
>
>  awk -F" " ' { if($0~/\|##\|/) { print; pre=$0;getline; if(pre!=$0) {print "\x22"$0 } } else { print } } '  double_quote.txt
101||101-C-01071||Integrity Testing of Bleed Back Filter (Emflon II ) Installed on ETC
Autoclave||PUBLIC||||Y||Y||||CFC6E8227CDB0A7AE040800AA5644B19||mdarling||2007.06.22
09:59:03|##| 102||102-CC-10||Sterilization and Leak Rate Testing of Stokes Style Freeze
"Drier||PUBLIC||||Y||Y||||CFC6E8227CDC0A7AE040800AA5644B19||mdarling||2007.06.22
10:00:05|##| 103||103-CC-13||CIP/SIP Leak Testing Hull 380sq. ft. Freeze
"Drier||PUBLIC||||Y||Y||||CFC6E8227CDD0A7AE040800AA5644B19||mdarling||2007.06.22
10:00:16|##| 104||104-CC-15||Emergency Situations & Alarms Involving the Automated Hull Freeze
"Drier Control||PUBLIC||||Y||Y||||CFC6E8227CDE0A7AE040800AA5644B19||mdarling||2007.06.22
10:00:32|##| strong text
>
```

Comment: Thank you sir, It worked .. will test for orignal file and let  you know in case of any helps.

Comment: yes.. please consider accepting the answer and an upvote.

Comment: Hello sir ,when i tried for the below test , it skipping to add double quotes in all the alternative lines 101|*|101-C-01071|*|Integrity Testing of Bleed Back Filter (Emflon II ) Installed on ETC Autoclave|*|PUBLIC|*||*|Y|*|Y|*||*|CFC6E8227CDB0A7AE040800AA5644B19|*|mdarling|*|2007.06.22 09:59:03|##|
102|*|102-CC-10|*|Sterilization and Leak Rate Testing of Stokes Style Freeze Drier|*|PUBLIC|*||*|Y|*|Y|*||*|CFC6E8227CDC0A7AE040800AA5644B19|*|mdarling|*|2007.06.22 10:00:05|##|

Comment: you can add the below line as well in the file103|*|103-CC-13|*|CIP/SIP Leak Testing Hull 380sq. ft. Freeze Drier|*|PUBLIC|*||*|Y|*|Y|*||*|CFC6E8227CDD0A7AE040800AA5644B19|*|mdarling|*|2007.06.22 10:00:16|##|
104|*|104-CC-15|*|Emergency Situations & Alarms Involving the Automated Hull Freeze Drier Control|*|PUBLIC|*||*|Y|*|Y|*||*|CFC6E8227CDE0A7AE040800AA5644B19|*|mdarling|*|2007.06.22 10:00:32|##|

Comment: the comment is stripping the newlines and printing in a single line.. could you please update it in the question itself.. you have to indent by 4 spaces

Comment: added in the question (input file (new file ))

Comment: check my EDIT1 in the answer

Comment: Sir, its giving me the same result (Dquoutes in alternative lines) -- resuls added in question itself.

Comment: looks like all the 4 lines have got |##|.. is that so ?.

Comment: file format is like this Delimeter |*| and end of  line always |##| . if there is any next line in the string alignment will get break , so my intension here is to add values with double quotes .

Comment: which means you want to always enclose all the lines in double quotes??..

Comment: yes , between delimeters (|*| ) should be enclosed , getting issue when  there is next line char